# Concerns about the size of odds-ratio estimates in binary logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, binary-data

I am creating some binary regressions and am wondering if I should be surprised by the size of the odds ratios.

In this particular example, the dependent variable indicates whether a student can meet a specified target in a second language. The explanatory variables are age as a continuous covariate and a measure of literacy in the first language. I am using SPSS to calculate the models, and they seem to be working fine (I have a large dataset of around 40,000 cases and very few empty cells in the data, no warning signs etc.) I have chosen to have 0 as the reference category for both outcome and categorical explanatory variable. As I understand it, the estimates I am seeing below tell me that if the student demonstrates L1 reading at level 4 they are 372 times as likely to be able to demonstrate the required skill in the second language.

The pattern of estimates is exactly as I would expect, my issue is with whether I should be concerned at the magnitude of the estimates, or whether this is usual in cases where there is clearly a strong connection between the two variables.

Many thanks!

KB

```
> Parameter          B         Exp(B)
> 
> (Intercept)      -3.077    
> Age                .075        1.078 
> [L1 Reading=4]    5.921      372.784 
> [L1 Reading=3]    5.330      206.438 
> [L1 Reading=2]    4.288       72.821 
> [L1 Reading=1]    3.025       20.594
> [L1 Reading=0]        0            0
```

Crosstabulation of L1 and DV:

> ```
> +-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
> |       |     0 |     1 |    2 |    3 |     4 |  Total|
> | 0.00  | 17537 |  6487 |  784 |  100 | 44    | 24952 |
> | 1.00  |  1284 |  9891 | 4287 | 1576 | 1328  | 18366 |
> | Total | 18821 | 16378 | 5071 | 1676 | 1372  | 43318 |
> +-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
> ```

Comment: It's hard to say, just from this, whether you should be concerned. Can you post the crosstabulation of L1 and the DV?

Comment: Sorry, some probs with the formatting there! Added it to the original query.

Comment: $\exp(0)=1$ and not $0$ (in the last row, `[L1 Reading=0]`)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for adding the table

Given this, I think the OR is fine. The logistic regression you posted also included another variable, but, in the table, the OR for L1 = 4 vs. L1 = 0 is $\frac{17537*1328}{1284*44} = 412.23$ which is actually a little larger than the one from the regression.

It's a very strong relationship.

Comment: Or written slightly differently, the odds of 1 in L1=4 is $\frac{1328}{44} = 30.182$. The odds of 1 in L1=0 is $\frac{1284}{17537} = .073$. The ratio of these odds is $\frac{30.182}{0.073} = 413.45$. Result differences are due to rounding.

Answer (score 7):

An important point needs to be added to Peter's good answer:

> 372 times as likely

is definitely not correct, although you would be about the ten gazillionth person to make this mistake.  A number close to 400 is the ratio not of two probabilities but of two odds.  The ratio of the two corresponding probabilities is [1328/(1328+44)] / [1284/(1284+17537)] = .968/.068 = **14**.

One might substitute for "probability" the term "risk" or even "chance" or "likelihood," but it is not correct to substitute any of the above in place of "odds."

Comment: Indeed. And one way to see this is to note that probabilities are always between 0 and 1, while odds can be anything.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to this -- I will certainly make sure I don't make that slip in writing up! -K ps-Can I just check, would it be more accurate to say: "the odds of this group demonstrating the skill in question are 372 times that of the reference group"?